# sphinx SQL search: excluding items

Tags: php, sphinx

Have my sphinx search going like so:

```
$result = $cl->query($_REQUEST['term'], 'myindex');
```

But I'd like to be able to filter out certain results that don't match a string value, something like:

```
$result = $cl->query($_REQUEST['term'] . " and somestringcol <> ''", 'myindex');
```

Is there some proper way to do this using the sphinx PHP API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SetFilter() to specify a filter on an attribute you defined.

See: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-1.10.html#attributes

Answer (score 0):

As Langdon, metions you can use the SetFilter(), but you may also be able to use the field search operator which is available in the extended search syntax to get a little  bit more specific with searching your index rather than attributes associated with it.

```
$result = $cl->query($_REQUEST['term'] . " @somestringcol -term", 'myindex');
```

The documentation for sphix provides many good examples: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/extended-syntax.html